# mvc connectionstrings questions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3

I wonder know how can i change the following data source from Ip to localhost on my mvc3 project in virtual directory.

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxCompany;Password=xxx@xxxx"/>
    <add name="DATABASEContext" connectionString="Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=DATABASEContext;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxCompany;Password=xxx@xxxx; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use a period `.`.  SQL Server translates period to localhost.  You may need to include an instance name.  If you're using SQLExpress, you'll most likely use `./SQLEXPRESS` as the data source.

Comment: More specific about what?  What do you need clarification about?

Comment: sorry. but when i changed it,it still give me error like "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server."

Comment: Make sure your instance of SQL Server is running.  It runs as a service, so you'll need to check the services control panel.

Comment: check the instance name (it will say what it is in the service name) and make sure your datasource is `./INSTANCENAME`

Comment: can not create the database after change to ./sqlexpress ,probably mine working directory is virtual directory